# Access files of Document Library site through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, onedrive

I was wondering if the two following queries are actually the same or supposed to be the same:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites/{spsite-id},{spweb-id}/drives`

and 

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/sites:/MYPATH:/drives`

I would like to access a Document Library Item in a sharepoint site through the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that both endpoints below are the same for getting all doc libraries or drive in a site according to the current beta [microsoft graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/site). The latter becomes handy when you dont know the site id yet but the relative site url.

- https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/[domain.sharepoint.com]:/[relative-url]:/drives
- https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/[site-id]/drives

  (e.g. site id: "cie493742.sharepoint.com,4af352a7-a53b-43d9-b0a3-da372b392ea0,52c490f3-3354-40b9-a3c9-fefb08cb5c88" )

Now to get the document library item

1. Get Document library id from list of drives

   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/[site-id]/drives
2. Get item id from list of items

   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/[site-id]/drives/[drive-id]/items
3. Final API call

   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/[site-id]/drives/[drive-id]/items/[item-id]

you could try experimenting the Graph API from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: the following works too: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/[drive-id]/root:/[doc-relative-path]/[doc-name.docx]